# Prove that a set of vectors $x, f(x), f^2(x), \dots, f^{m-1}(x) $is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume V is a vectorspace over the field K and $f \in End V$. Let $x\in V$ be such that for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$

$f^m(x)=0$ and $f^{m-1}(x)\neq 0$.

I have to prove that the set of vectors $x, f(x), f^2(x), \dots, f^{m-1}(x)$ is linearly independent.

(Also to clarify $f^k=f * f*…*f $(k times).)

Unfortunately at the moment I don't have any idea how to start proving that. If anyone has some tips or comments, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: $f^{m-1}\neq 0$ or $f^{m-1}(x)\neq 0$？

Comment: $f^{m-1}(x)\neq 0$, sorry I edited it now

Answer (score 0):

To prove lineally independentneses, we take $a_0,\dots,a_{m-1}\in K$ s.t.
$0=\sum_{0\le i\le m-1}a_if^i(x)$.

Then  $0=f(0)=f(\sum_{0\le i\le m-1}a_if^i(x))=\sum_{0\le i\le m-1}a_if^{i+1}(x)=\sum_{0\le i\le m-2}a_if^{i+1}(x)$.
We iterate to act $f$ in $(m-1)$ times,  we get $a_0f^{m-1}(x)=0$. So we get $a_0=0$. By induction we get $a_1=0, \dots, a_{m-1
}=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!